Ubuntu acpi/interrupts issues not solved by dist upgrade
after each reboot a have to run this list of commands to my free my processor from overload
sudo -s
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13
exit

i tried to upgrade my OS to the latest - no result
here are my system parameters:

ASUS N551JW
Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
RAM 16Gb

now i use these OS & kernels

Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x64

5.15.0-76-generic

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

6.8.0-47-generic



i decided to split my previous question to get answers to all my questions

Have you tried adding boot parameter acpi_mask_gpe=0x13 to solve your first issue?

@mpboden no, i'll try, thank u,
but that's not the main issue

This issue can sometimes be resolved by creating a systemd service that automatically runs your commands at boot:
Create a new service file:
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/disable-gpe13.service

Add the following content:
[Unit]
Description=Disable GPE13 on boot

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13'
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Enable the service:
sudo systemctl enable disable-gpe13.service


this helped to bypass the least of those issues - thank u
